# How to search a date from a timestamped column using CURDATE()?

Tags: mysql, date-formatting

I'm trying this query:

```
SELECT date(mydate) FROM invoice where date(mydate) = CURDATE()
```

I can't get any result but when I enter the date i get a result:

```
SELECT date(mydate) FROM invoice where date(mydate) = '2015-02-12'
```

Comment: What type does have mydate column?

Comment: @KostiaShiian "timestamp"

Comment: try to use # CURDATE() #

Comment: not working mate, error occurred

Comment: I don't  know where you live, but where I am it's been `2015-02-13` for 19 hours. Are you sure "now" is not 13th where you are too?

Comment: hehehe take it ez.. i have a prob with my bios my system date is 2015-02-12

Comment: try this "SELECT * FROM invoice
WHERE myDate &lt;=NOW()

Comment: @DoorDUthpala:Can you provide few sample data in your `mydate` column?

Comment: thanx mate.. but prob solved there was a trouble with data :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 SELECT date FROM invoice WHERE date = NOW()
```